# Notation of the Domain of a Multivariate Function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let us consider the following multivariate function: $f(x,y,z)$, where $x\in\mathbb{R},y\in\mathbb{R},z\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in[0,1],y\in[0,1],z=\{1,2,3,...k\}$.

For the function's domain I suggest the following notation: $$f(x,y,z):X\mapsto \mathbb{R}~, X=\{x\in\mathbb{R},y\in\mathbb{R},z\in\mathbb{N}\mid 0\leq x,y\leq 1,z=\overline{1,k}\}$$

How can I precisely write the function's domain is the above mentioned notation clear?

Comment: I would just write $[0,1]^2\times\{1,\dots,k\}$ for the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, $f: [0;1]{\times}[0;1]{\times}([1;k]\cap\Bbb N)\mapsto \Bbb R$

Comment: So can I write $$f{x,y,z);X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, X=[0,1]\times [0,1]\times ([1,k]\cap \mathbb{N})$$? Is my notation incomplete or worng? Thank you.

Comment: $\ddot-$  Yeah, the notation seems comprehensible.  The MathJax formatting needs work though.